# Calling location.reload() and location.assign() sequentially

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reload a page and then access a file download url in javascript like so:

```
function reloadAndDownload() {
   location.reload();
   location.assign(fileDownloadURL);
}
```

I find that in the above example, only the "location.assign()" seems to execute.

If I have this:

```
function reloadAndDownload() {
   location.assign(fileDownloadURL);
   location.reload();
}
```

then only the "location.reload()" seems to execute.  Is it possible to call both these functions sequentially as described and have them both execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Javascript runs in window, and each of location functions triggers its reload. You may open a new window.